# I am trying to build an array in java that has multiple data types

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner in programming java, I have a question which asks of me to input: the student name, id, math score, english score, and science score then calculate his total and average. So I am trying to make it into a 2d array yet I don't know how to turn string array into int. Is there a way to have one array with multiple data types(char, int, string etc)?
heres my code so far

```
int columns = input.nextInt();
        int rows=5;
        int StudentName=0;
        int StudentID=1;
        int math=2;
        int English=3;
        int Science = 4;
        int i = 0;
        String[][] newArray = new String[columns][rows];
        for (i = 0; i<columns;i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Student Name ");
            newArray[i][StudentName] = input.nextLine();           
            System.out.println("Enter Student ID ");
            newArray[i][StudentID] = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Student Math Score ");
            newArray[i][math] = input.nextLine(); 
            System.out.println("Enter Student English Score ");
            newArray[i][English] = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Student Science Score ");
            newArray[i][Science] = input.nextLine();
        }
        for(i = 0; i < columns; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
               System.out.println(newArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: just use an array of type Object

Comment: Even better would be to define a custom class to hold the data you need (and have an array of that)

Comment: @Stultuske I'm sorry, but that is a terrible suggestion, especially as the OP wants to store primitives as well as object references, which is an impossibility.

Comment: @JimGarrison welcome in a world that contains wrapper Objects. ok, how would you create an array that can contain both primitives and Objects (of any type) ?

Comment: You can't, and if you are trying to create a polymorphic array your design has serious issues.  That is not what arrays are for in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array of Object. Because, in the end, anything in Java is an Object (or has an "Object sibling" - like the Integer class for primitive int values). Therefore an array of Object can be used to store the various different elements that make up a pupil.

But that is the **wrong** approach. You use classes and objects to **model** the entities your code has to deal with.

Thus create a **class** that represents a Student. And that class has fields such as name, id, grades. And then, in the end create a one-dimensional array of `Student`! That is the **essence** of OO programming: to create helpful abstractions, instead of *coupling* your data by stuffing it into arrays and remembering which index "relates" things that belong together. Instead: make that relationship explicit!

Comment: No, not _"anything in Java is an Object"_, you have forgotten primitive values (int, long, float, double, boolean).

Comment: "anything in Java is an Object" => this is incorrect, since `Object` only apply for reference types (including wrapper classes), primitives are not.

Comment: I agree, that wasn't precise enough. I updated the answer accordingly (@JimGarrison thanks, too).

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a domain object which will be your data structure and immutable;

For an example:

public class StudentInfo implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final String StudentName;
private final int StudentID;


public StudentInfo (String StudentName, int StudentID) {
    this.StudentName= StudentName;
    this.StudentID= StudentID;

}

public String getStudentName() {
    return StudentName;
}
```

//More access method.

One builder method to create the object incrementally

```
public class StudentInfoBuilder {
        private String StudentName;
        private int StudentID;

        private StudentInfo() {
        }

        public static JobInfoBuilder newBuilder() {
            return new JobInfoBuilder();

        }

        public JobInfoBuilder withJobName(String StudentName) {
            this.StudentName = StudentName;
            return this;
        }


        public JobInfo build() {
            return new StudentInfo(StudentName, StudentID);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To be simple and clear, you could do following steps:

Create `Student` **model** with all required fileds (with required types):

```
public class Student {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String mathScore;
    private String englishScore;
    private String scienceScore;
}
```

Define method for read all students from console:

```
public static Student[] readStudents(Scanner input) {
    Student[] students = new Student[input.nextInt()];

    for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        Student student = new Student();
        students[i] = student;

        System.out.println("Enter Student Name ");
        student.setName(input.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter Student ID ");
        student.setId(input.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter Student Math Score ");
        student.setMathScore(input.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter Student English Score ");
        student.setEnglishScore(input.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter Student Science Score ");
        student.setScienceScore(input.nextLine());
    }

    return students;
}
```

Define method to print all students to console:

```
public static void print(Student[] students) {
    for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        Student student = students[i];

        System.out.printf("Student Name: %s", student.getName());
        System.out.printf("Student ID: %s", student.getId());
        System.out.printf("Student Math Score: %s", student.getMathScore());
        System.out.printf("Student English Score: %s", student.getEnglishScore());
        System.out.printf("Student Science Score: %s", student.getScienceScore());

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**P.S.** You could use either `array` or `list` as collection. In general: do use `array` if you do not plan to modify size of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Below is the sample code. You can follow the same procedure and try calculating the sum and avg.

```
class Student{  

    String name;  
    int mark1;
    int mark2;
    Student(String name,int mark1,int mark2){   
        this.name=name;  
        this.mark1=mark1; 
        this.mark2=mark2;
    }  
}

public class DiffDataType {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //Creating user defined class objects  
            Student s1=new Student("Mark",90,75);  
            Student s2=new Student("John",74,65);  
            Student s3=new Student("Simon",65,86); 

            ArrayList<Student> al=new ArrayList<Student>();
            al.add(s1);
            al.add(s2);  
            al.add(s3);  

            Iterator itr=al.iterator();  

            //traverse elements of ArrayList object  
            while(itr.hasNext()){  
                Student st=(Student)itr.next();  
                System.out.println(st.name+" "+st.mark1+""+st.mark2);  
            }  
        }

    }
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Get accustomed to just a couple of other data structures and java statements:

```
class Student {
    String name;
    String id;
    //int mathScore;
    //int englishScore;
    //int scienceScore;
    int[] scores = new int[3];
}
```

As arrays cannot grow, use a List, implemented as ArrayList.

```
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {

        System.out.println("Enter Student Name ");
        String line = input.nextLine();
        if (line.equals("end")) {
            break;
        }

        // Create a new student:
        Student student = new Student();

        student.name = line;           
        System.out.println("Enter Student ID ");
        student.id = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Student Math Score ");
        String line = input.nextLine();
        student.scores[0] = Integer.parseInt(line); 
        System.out.println("Enter Student English Score ");
        line = input.nextLine();
        student.scores[1] = Integer.parseInt(line); 
        System.out.println("Enter Student Science Score ");
        line = input.nextLine();
        student.scores[2] = Integer.parseInt(line); 

        // Add the student to the list:
        students.add(student);
    }

    // One way to walk through the list:
    for (Student student : students) {}
        System.out.printf("Name %s, ID %s, Math: %d.%n",
                student.name, student.id, student.scores[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think It's better to create Student class like in previous answers, and then store them into Map:

```
Map<Integer, Student> students = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    Student student = new Student("Mark", 90, 75);  
    map.put(i, student);
}
```

So you can iterate over the map, (`using students.entrySet()`) and get student by key (`students.get(3)`)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers which stated that you should create your own Student class are correct, however I will show you a way to create an array that supports multiple types:

Make the array of type Object and instead of using primitive values (i.e, int, float, char, etc) use their wrapper classes (i.e, Integer, Float, Character)

Keep in mind that this will use much more memory.